# Getting code coverage 0% despite getting print statements in Django development server

Tags: python, django, integration-testing, code-coverage, automation-testing

I have a django project running on local development server. It has different remote DB server.

I am trying run API integration tests. Tests are running and giving expected output. Also print statements are generated in console for APIs I am running tests for. But still code coverage is shown 0% for file which was executed after API hit.

This is my sample test function

```
class Test_Login_User_FR_and_Dispatcher:

    BASE_URL = http://passcodev.localhost:8000
    FR_LOGIN_ENDPOINT = '/api/user/login/'


    # TESTCASE FOR SUCCESSFULL LOGIN OF USER
    def test_successfull_login_user(self, success_login):
        successfull_login = requests.post(f'{self.BASE_URL}{self.FR_LOGIN_ENDPOINT}',json=success_login)
        assert successfull_login.status_code == 200
```

I am using coverage.py for code coverage report generation.

I tried coverage.py, pytest cov. But still I am unable to find any leads to troubleshoot this problem.

---